# Copiar una colección de MongoDB utilizando pymongo y pegarla en otra colección

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Quiero copiar una collection `coll` para hacer un backup en una base de datos en MongoDB. Entonces intenté:

```
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(
...             f"mongodb+srv://{user}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/es_eso_importante?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
>>>
>>> db = client['test']
>>> source = db['coll']
>>> destination = db['coll_backup']
>>> pipeline = [ {"$match": {}},
...              {"$out": "coll_backup"}]
>>> db.coll.aggregate(pipeline)
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000214564785F8>
```

Pero no tengo ningun cambio sobre MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente. Recuerda que el método `aggregate` de `pymongo` devuelve un [`command_cursor`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html), y dado que los resultados los vuelcas en otra colección no obtendrás documentos de vuelta. Toma en cuenta que el `dashboard` de MongoAtlas no se actualiza automáticamente, debes hacer la actualización de la vista manualmente para que veas los cambios producidos. Saludos